# Symfony 4 - Multiple authentication

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

Good afternoon,

Here I am working on Symfony 4 and on the Symfony Security module.
I need to customize the authentication of my users without using plugins such as Fosuser.
This is for the following reasons:

The user connects to a "main" server (ldap) with his login/password
I need to be able to retrieve his credentials to test his account on other ldap servers in parallel.

When the user is authenticated on the main one, the user is redirected to a page telling him if everything is ok or not on the other servers. In case it is not, he has the possibility to update his account.

But the documentation deals with "simple" cases and here I am a little lost.
I tested several possibilities (authentication with Guard, test of creation of a personalized provider...) without results.

I would need to understand the mechanisms of symfony authentication to create a custom authentication.
If anyone has a lead to guide me, that would be great.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Post some code about the parts you are struggling with.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to divide your action into 2 stages:

1. Authenticate by LDAP against first server, i.e. with [Symfony LDAP Component](https://symfony.com/components/Ldap) - this can be done by standard authentication form and FOSUserBundle
2. When you are already authenticated interact with second server in controller action. This can be done by writing entire code in Controler or in service designed to interact with this LDAP server. You can even use the same Symfony LDAP Component as before, but you will need to configure another instance of service by hand.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for your answer. The problem, I know how to solve it in simple php without using the symfony security bundle.
The real problem is that when authenticating the user, I would like to keep his login and password in session. Currently I only get the login.
This would allow me to perform the connection test on the other servers after the first authentication.
I have looked at options like eraseCredendials in the configuration file but without results. After I do not know if it is very advisable to keep the login and password in session. I may not have the right method in mind.

Comment: If you need to store password in session, you definitely should encrypt it. Store plain password in session is not safe. To sotre password in session (encrypted or not) you will need to overload FOSuserBundle controller that handle login form and make authentication or even better the service that is uset by controller to authenticate. I think it is FOSUserManager but i'm not sure.